# Can't add UDID to provisioning profile for ad hoc deployment

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile

[image]

I don't see a "+" symbol or anything.  It only gives me these 3 options when I am making a new provisional file.

Answer (score 0):

You add your devices under a different section first. Then you create/edit your provisioning profile.

Comment: I've clicked on "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles" and i still see nowhere to add devices :/ nevermind found it!

Comment: After clicking on "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles", click on "All" under "Devices".

Answer (score 0):

After you click "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles", click "Devices" and this is where you can add devices.